# jQuery live search - Go back to first result after the page has found all available results

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, mobile, jquery-plugins

I'm using mark.js plugin that allows to search text on page, it finds text while you type and if you hit the Enter key, you'll jump to the next result until it has found and highlighted all results.
The only problem is that when it reaches the last result, it gives the search as concluded and the search can't be restarted from the first result if you hit Enter.

I need to be able to scroll back to the first result after the last result has been found (Just like it happens when you're searching something using Google Chrome Find Box (Control + F).

[[Working Fiddle]](https://jsfiddle.net/70okvfr1/6/)
You need to scroll the result tab in the fiddle a little bit, in order to see the Search Box.

The following function is responsible for scrolling between the results, it will jump to the last (Next) found text on page:

```
done: function() {
                var mark = $('mark[data-markjs]').last();   // Scroll to last <mark>
                if (mark.length) {  
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: mark.offset().top-100}, 100);
                }
            }
```

This one is responsible for using the Enter key to trigger the previous function:

```
if(e.which==13){ // 13 = enter key
            e.preventDefault();
            arrowOffset++;
        }
```

Thx in advance.

Comment: Anyone? Is it that hard? =|

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation you provided I was able to figure out an implementation that highlighted all words and allowed cycling of words. In general the changes are as follows:

1. Create an array named *offsets* to keep track of the current "top offset" of highlighted words. This is the measure of distance from the top of the container to the word being highlighted.

   ```
   arrowOffset = 0;
   var offsets = [];
   ```
2. Change your *options.done* function to following implementation: grab all the offsets from the search and store them in our array *offsets*;

   ```
   var m = $('mark[data-markjs]');

   offsets = [];

   for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
       offsets.push($(m[i]).offset().top);
   }
   ```
3. Change your "keyup" event handler to the following implementation:

   ```
   e.preventDefault();

   if (e.which == 13 || e.which == 40) { // 13 = enter key, 40 = down arrow
     if (++arrowOffset >= offsets.length) {
       arrowOffset = 0;
     }
   } else if (e.which == 38) { // 38 = up arrow
     if (--arrowOffset < 0) {
       arrowOffset = offsets.length - 1;
     }
   }

   $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: offsets[arrowOffset] - 100
   }, 100);
   ```
4. Finally, at the end of your function, call

   ```
   $("input[name='keyword']").on("keyup", mark);
   $("input[type='checkbox']").on("change", mark);
   ```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/billiford/p3026h8s/)

Comment: They don't have a rich documentation, but there is a part talking about the highlighting:
4.1 mark()
A method to highlight custom search terms.
https://markjs.io

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/billiford/p3026h8s/)

Is this better? Let me know and I'll change my answer.

Comment: It is. Way better, now all results are shown. But it looks like there is a bug with the scroller. If you type 1 and repeat the search using enter, you notice that the problem happens aftter the search is repeated, in the top of the page.

Comment: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/billiford/p3026h8s/). This is the best I can do for now. It's more efficient in the sense that it only calculates word offsets when the search is done. It stores these offsets in an array *offsets* and parses key input to change *arrowOffsets* to the current offset value. It works with enter, up, and down arrows.

Comment: Please change your answer to the newest fiddle, I'm going to mark it as the best one.

Comment: Updated answer. I'll try to look into your other question soon.